# question about maven clean

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

Why does maven download dependencies when I run `mvn clean`? can I turn that off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run as `mvn -o clean`

Answer (score 3):

> Why does maven download dependencies when I run `mvn clean`?

AFAIK, it doesn't, Maven doesn't perform a dependency resolution during `clean` (I just cross checked that and I confirm it doesn't, at least not with Maven 2.2.1 and the clean plugin 2.2). Having that said, it seems that attaching a plugin to the clean phase can interfere  and cause a dependency resolution (e.g. this happens with antrun as reported in [JBBUILD-585](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBBUILD-585)). Maybe it's your case.

> can I turn that off?

If you are doing some fancy stuff during the clean phase, remove it :) Another option would be to run maven offline during a clean (with the `-o` or `--offline` options).

Comment: It downloads the clean plugin when you clean though, doesn't it?

Comment: @wds Indeed, the first time you run it, like any other plugin. But I don't think this is what the question is about (the question explicitly mentions *dependencies*).

Comment: Someone unfamiliar with maven nomenclature might confuse the two. In any case, just mentioning it for completeness sake.